# Resolution Scaling in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution

i wanted to ask you if there is a Resolution Scale Option like in Unreal Engine in Unity too. I have looked around the internet but didn't found anything.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html ?

Comment: its not about the canvas

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to scale objects that are not on the canvas based on the resolution then offhand I can't think of anything. However, it would be fairly easy to implement something that does this.

Create a Script and attach it to every object that should scale based on the current resolution.

```
    public class ScaleObjectFromRes : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 targetResoultion = new Vector2(1920, 1080); //can be changed here or elsewhere
    private bool matchWidth = true; //0=width, 1=height  used to maintain aspect ratio


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        float difference = CalculateDifference();
        ScaleObj(difference);
    }

    void ScaleObj(float diff)
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale += (gameObject.transform.localScale * (diff/100));
    }

    private float CalculateDifference()
    {
        Vector2 actualResolution = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
        Vector2 change = actualResolution-targetResoultion;

        Vector2 percentChange = (change / targetResoultion) * 100;

        //match width/height
        if (matchWidth)
        {
            return percentChange.x;
        }
        else
        {
            return percentChange.y;
        }

    }
```

This scales the object based on the percent difference between the target resolution and the actual resolution. We can choose to match the difference based upon the width or height to guarantee a constant ratio for the object. This assumes the object's scale vector's magnitude is 1. Hope this helps!